# Relative path to import sass file does not work

Tags: sass

[Here is the tree structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tNv2.png)

I am trying to import one scss file (available in theme named **variables.scss**) into the another scss file (named **tick-tock.component.scss**) but I receive the following error message.

***Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../../theme/variables***

here is how I am trying to import the file.

[here is how I am trying to import the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9UKR.png)

but if I give the absolute path it works like the following it works. (which ofcourse is wrong way)
@import 'C:/My-Source/angular-component-library/src/theme/variables';

Comment: What tool are you using to build the scss?

Comment: webpack
visual studio code

Comment: Are you sure your file name is "_variables.scss" not the "variables.scss"?

Answer (score 0):

partials/import must be prefixed with an underscore like '_variables.scss'
you can read more about it here in the section "partials": http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: I have tried the given solution but it does not work